# Web Forms Url Routing in Mono

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nginx, mono

I'm new to `mono` and trying to run a simple hello world application with routing. While my application runs fine on IIS, I'm getting a 404 error when I browse to the root of the site. I've got my route mapped as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("default", String.Empty, "~/site/home.aspx")
```

Browsing directly to the file (`http://myhostname/site/home.aspx`) works.

I tried using the following `web.config` -- both with and without the `system.webServer` section:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

I'm using `nginx` with `fastcgi-mono-server4` and my `fastcgi_index` is set to `Default.aspx` (I tried lowercase as well as `Index.aspx`).

Anything that I'm missing here or does mono only support routing with MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an `nginx` configuration issue. I hadn't specified the `root` in my site's config.

```
server {
   listen 80;

   location / {
     root /var/www/comparebetween/;
     fastcgi_index /;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

I've seen most blogs suggesting bare minimum config by setting the `fastcgi_index` to `Default.aspx` and specifying `fastcgi_pass` and `fastcgi_params` but I hope the above helps someone who runs into the same problem.